# Can't loop geocoding?

Tags: ios, for-loop, geolocation, clgeocoder

At the moment I'm working on an application for the iPad, which at a certain point should show a list of cities with next to these cities the distance from the users current location.

I'm using a loop which uses a database I built earlier. This is the code:

```
NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, Nederland", [info2 objectForKey:@"stadsnaam"]];
    [self.geocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D firstLocation = location.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"%f,%f", firstLocation.latitude, firstLocation.longitude);
    }];
```

This piece of code is inside a for loop. But the first time it is run, it just returns 0.0000

The second time the loop is activated (and I'm sure it runs more than one time) it returns only the distance between the current location and the FIRST city.

The app gets the city names from this piece of code:`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, Nederland", [info2 objectForKey:@"stadsnaam"]]`

Which I verified and works. I would like to avoid using the Google API because I will be making more than the maximum request a day probably XD

Any help is appreciated, please inform me if anything isn't completely clear and thanks in advance!

Comment: anything in error inside the block?

Comment: firstLocation = placemarks[0].location.coordinate;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/) for `-geocodeAddressString:completionHandler:`:

> After initiating a forward-geocoding request, do not attempt to initiate another forward- or reverse-geocoding request.

You can use CLGeocoder's `geocoding` property to determine whether a geocoding operation is in progress.

Comment: I might be all wrong about this. But in an earlier stage in the same App I have a search for the location in which the user can simply type his hometown. It works multiple times. How is this different from that?

Comment: @ChrisvanSchayk Timing. The loop that you're trying to create will attempt geocoding operations a lot faster than you can type in a hometown name and tap a button. Your old app probably worked because the geocoder happened to finish before the next request was submitted.

Comment: Okay, I actually fixed it by making a loop with a delay of 0.05 seconds for each iteration! Now it works ^^ And it also provides a nice visual effect as well.. Maybe I'll add some animations to it now I'm at it. Thanks again Caleb!

Comment: Glad to help. You should really check the `geocoding` property as well -- 0.05 seconds might be fine most of the time, but a slow network connection or other factors could easily cause that to change.